# glpk exits by saying too many constraint coefficients

Tags: python, pyomo, glpk

I am using the glpk solver with pyomo on a problem that involves about 40,000 decision variables and 50,000 constraints. However, I am getting the following error while running the code:

```
glp_set_mat_row: i = 80406; len = 5772; too many constraint coefficients
Error detected in file ..\src\api\prob1.c at line 764
ERROR: Solver (glpk) returned non-zero return code (3221226505)
```

Is this problem too large for the glpk solver to handle? Is it possible to increase the tolerance of glpk?

Thank you.

Comment: GLPK like other LP/MIP solvers, prefers the problem to be **sparse**.  This is almost always the case for practical problems, but there are exceptions. Large, dense problems are more difficult. They need good solvers and machines with a lot of memory. It is noted that sometimes dense problems are the result of bad modeling.